# dtrace: failed to compile script probe description pid29441::*Slave_open_temp_tables*:return does not match any probes?

Tags: mysql, dtrace

Due to [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/45504/innobackupex-what-causes-slave-open-temp-tables-did-not-become-zero-after-waiti) problem, I'm going to use [dtrace](https://github.com/dtrace4linux/linux) to find out what the slave SQL thread is doing with temporary tables follow [this](http://www.arubin.org/blog/2009/10/02/using-dtrace-to-find-queries-creating-disk-temporary-tables/) guide.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/sbin/dtrace -s

#pragma D option quiet
dtrace:::BEGIN
{
    printf("Tracing... Hit Ctrl-C to end.\n");
}

pid$target::*mysql_parse*:entry
{
    self->query = copyinstr(arg1);
}

pid$target::*Slave_open_temp_tables*:return
{
    @query[self->query] = count();
}
```

and this is what I got when running:

```
# ./Slave_open_temp_tables.d -p `pgrep -x mysqld`
proc-stub:rd_event_enable
proc-stub:rd_errstr err=26
dtrace: failed to compile script ./Slave_open_temp_tables.d: line 14: probe description pid29441::*Slave_open_temp_tables*:return does not match any probes
User defined signal 1
```

I also have tried with `create_myisam_tmp_table` but got the same result.

Where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have MySQL installed to look for you, but the `-l` option to `dtrace` will tell you what probes are available, from which you should be able to figure out what you're doing wrong.

```
$ dtrace -ln 'pid$target::*Slave_open_temp_tables*:return' -p `pgrep -x mysqld`
```

Or try using a less-specific name such as `*open_temp_tables*` or `*tables*` or even `*` to get a broader set of results... it could be that the function no longer exists in your target process due to changes in the source code of MySQL.

Also, I assume you've checked the output of `pgrep -x mysqld` to make sure it's a valid input pid?